# How to import localForage to Typescript project using ///<reference path …> tag?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, localforage

I have a project in Typescript and I want to use the dependency "localForage": https://github.com/localForage/localForage.

I installed it by the following npm command:

> npm install @types/localforage --save

I used:

```
/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />
///<reference path="node_modules/localforage/typings/localforage.d.ts"/>

import lf = require("./node_modules/localforage");

lf.setItem("blabla", "blabla");
lf.getItem("blabla", (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

When I ran it in the browser, I got the Error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "localforage" from "undefined"

I used this link to solve this issue: https://www.tomsdev.com/blog/2015/packaging-typescript-module-publish-npm-release/

Comment: Do you **have** to use `reference` tag? Why not just `import` it into your code?

Comment: as far as I can see, you are using modules. But this won't work in browser unless you use some bundler/module loader...

Comment: Can you give me a code example the works?